# Triggering function when clicking generated objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code to generate random objects in a specific canvas
i want  to make those objects clickable so if i click on one of the objects i trigger a function im not really good with javascript so i need some help
here is the code

````js
function spawnRandomObject() {

    var t ;



    if (Math.random() < 0.50) {
        t = "red";
    } else {
        t = "yellow";
    }

    var object = {
        type: t,
        x: Math.random() * (canvas.width - 30) + 15,
        y: spawnLineY,
    }

    objects.push(object);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

To add an event listener you should have a HTML element like so:

```
<div id="clickable-object">Click this Object</div>
```

Then in your script file you assign that element to a variable and attach an event listener to it.

```
let object = document.getElementById('clickable-object');

object.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('This object has been clicked');
}
```

In order for your javascript to be able to interact with the html you need to include your js file in the html file.